# MultiForm validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I validate a multi step form on next rather and finally with submit?

for the moment my code validate only the last step with submit button but not the previous step of my form.

here is my .php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>NGS Requisition Form</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#service").change(function() {
                // foo is the id of the other select box 
                if ($(this).val() == "WES") {
                    $("#analyses").show();
                }else{
                    $("#analyses").hide();
                } 
            });
        });


        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#service").change(function() {
                // foo is the id of the other select box 
                if ($(this).val() == "IDP") {
                    $("#idp").show();
                }else{
                    $("#idp").hide();
                } 
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#service").change(function() {
                // foo is the id of the other select box 
                if ($(this).val() == "ICP") {
                    $("#icp").show();
                }else{
                    $("#icp").hide();
                } 
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#service").change(function() {
                // foo is the id of the other select box 
                if ($(this).val() == "STP") {
                    $("#stp").show();
                }else{
                    $("#stp").hide();
                } 
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header form -->

<h1 class="top-title"> Genomics Requisition Form </h1>
<h3 class="info-title"> * Please ensure ALL the information is thoroughly filled out. </h3>


 <!-- multistep form -->


<form id="msform" action="test.php">


  <!-- progressbar -->

  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Patient Information</li>
    <li>Medical Information</li>
    <li>Specimen Information</li>
    <li>Physician Information</li>
    <li>Requester Information</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset  id="fieldset1">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Patient Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 1/5</h3>


<table width=50% align="right"><tr>
    <td><h3 class="ft-subtitle">Male </h3><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> </td>
    <td><h3 class="ft-subtitle">Female </h3><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"></td>
</tr></table>

    <input type="text" name="pname" placeholder="Patient Full Name" required />
    <input type="text" name="pmrn" placeholder="Medical Record N°" />
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">DOB</h3>
    <input type="date" name="pdob" required />
    <input type="text" name="peid" placeholder="Emirates ID" required />
    <input type="text" name="ptel" placeholder="Phone" />
    <input type="email" name="pemail" placeholder="E-mail" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>



  <fieldset  id="fieldset2"> 
    <h2 class="fs-title">Medical Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 2/5</h3>

    <select name="suspdiag"> 
        <option value="">-- Suspected diagnosis --</option>
        <option value="Comprehensive Autism">Comprehensive Autism</option>
        <option value="Comprehensive Cardio-vascular">Comprehensive Cardio-vascular</option>
        <option value="Comprehensive Cardio-myopathy">Comprehensive Cardio-myopathy</option>
        <option value="Sudden Cardiac Arrest">Sudden Cardiac Arrest</option>
        <option value="Cystic Fibrosis">Cystic Fibrosis</option>
        <option value="Diabetes MODY">Diabetes MODY</option>
        <option value="Comprehensive Epilepsy">Comprehensive Epilepsy</option>
        <option value="Gastro-Intestinal">Gastro-Intestinal</option>
        <option value="Mitochondrial Disorder(Nuclear genes only)">Mitochondrial Disorder(Nuclear genes only)</option>
        <option value="Mitochondrial Disorder (Mitochondrial Genome)">Mitochondrial Disorder (Mitochondrial Genome)</option>
        <option value="Congenital Muscular Dystrophy">Congenital Muscular Dystrophy</option>
        <option value="LGMD Muscular Dystrophy">LGMD Muscular Dystrophy</option>
        <option value="Neuro-Muscular">Neuro-Muscular</option>
        <option value="Pulmonary Disease">Pulmonary Disease</option>
        <option value="Blood Disorder">Blood Disorder</option>
        <option value="Deafness">Deafness</option>
        <option value="Dysmorphic - Dysplasia">Dysmorphic - Dysplasia</option>
        <option value="Endocrine Disorder">Endocrine Disorder</option>
        <option value="Metabolic Disorder">Metabolic Disorder</option>
        <option value="Neurological Disorder">Neurological Disorder</option>
        <option value="Pelvic Inflammatory Disease">Pelvic Inflammatory Disease</option>
        <option value="Renal Disease">Renal Disease</option>
        <option value="Visual Disorder">Visual Disorder</option>
        <option value="Warfarin sensitivity">Warfarin sensitivity</option>
        <option value="Inherited Breast Cancer">Inherited Breast Cancer</option>
        <option value="Comprehensive Inherited Cancer">Comprehensive Inherited Cancer</option>
        <option value="Somatic Cancer">Somatic Cancer</option>
    </select>

    <textarea rows="2" name="phistory" placeholder="Medical History (current disorder)" required></textarea>
    <textarea rows="2" name="ptrt" placeholder="Current treatments"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="2" name="pclinical" placeholder="Other relevant clinical history"></textarea>
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">Previous Genetic testing performed ?</h3>
    <br>
    <table width=50% align="right"><tr>
        <td><h3 class="ft-subtitle">No </h3><input type="radio" name="ptest" value="no" checked> </td>
        <td><h3 class="ft-subtitle">YES </h3><input type="radio" name="ptest" value="yes"></td>
    </tr></table>
    <br><br>
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">If YES, please give more information</h3>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="ptestinfo" placeholder="other test" />

    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">Please indicate if your are :</h3>
    <br>
    <table width=50% align="right"><tr>
        <td><h3 class="ft-subtitle">Proband </h3><input type="radio" name="proband" value="yes" checked> </td>
        <td><h3 class="ft-subtitle">Family member </h3><input type="radio" name="proband" value="no"></td>
    </tr></table>
    <br><br>
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">If Family member, please give proband Emirate ID°</h3>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="2" name="fmeid" placeholder="Emirates ID N°1 , Emirates ID N°2 , Emirates ID N°3 ..."></textarea>

    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" /> 
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset  id="fieldset3">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Specimen Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 3/5</h3>
    <input type="text" name="stype" placeholder="Specimen Type (Blood, Swab ...)" required/>
    <input type="text" name="sorigin" placeholder="Site of origin (If relevant)" />
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">Number of samples</h3>

        <select id="nbsample" name="nbsample" required>
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>

    <br><br>
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">Collection date & time</h3>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="colltime" value="2017-09-18T10:00" required/>
    <input type="text" name="collby" placeholder="Collected by" />

    <br><br>
        <select id="service" name="service" required>
                <option value="">-- Assay Requested--</option>
                <option value="WGS">Whole Genome Sequencing (HGG-125)</option>
                <option value="WES">Whole exome Sequencing</option>
                <option value="IDP">INHERITED DISORDERS – TARGETED PANELS</option>
                <option value="ICP">INHERITED CANCER PANELS</option>
                <option value="STP">SOLID TUMOUR PANELS</option>
        </select>

        <p id="analyses" style="display:none;">
        <select id="bioinfo" name="bioinfo">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="HGE-126">Full bioinformatics analysis (HGE-126)</option>
                <option value="HGE-127">FASTQ data only (HGE-127)</option>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p id="idp" style="display:none;">
        <select id="panelx" name="panelx" >
                    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="HGT-128">Comprehensive Autism (HGT-128)</option>
                <option value="HGT-129">Comprehensive Cardio-vascular (HGT-129)</option>
                <option value="HGT-130">Comprehensive Cardio-myopathy (HGT-130)</option>
                <option value="HGT-131">Sudden Cardiac Arrest (HGT-131)</option>
                <option value="HGT-132">Cystic Fibrosis (HGT-132)</option>
                <option value="HGT-133">Diabetes MODY (HGT-133)</option>
                <option value="HGT-134">Comprehensive Epilepsy (HGT-134)</option>
                <option value="HGT-135">Gastro-Intestinal (HGT-135)</option>
                <option value="HGT-136">Mitochondrial Disorder(Nuclear genes only) (HGT-136)</option>
                <option value="HGT-137">Mitochondrial Disorder (Mitochondrial Genome) (HGT-137)</option>
                <option value="HGT-138">Congenital Muscular Dystrophy (HGT-138)</option>
                <option value="HGT-139">LGMD Muscular Dystrophy (HGT-139)</option>
                <option value="HGT-140">Neuro-Muscular (HGT-140)</option>
                <option value="HGT-141">Pulmonary Disease (HGT-141)</option>
                <option value="HGT-142">Blood Disorder (HGT-142)</option>
                <option value="HGT-143">Deafness (HGT-143)</option>
                <option value="HGT-144">Dysmorphic - Dysplasia (HGT-144)</option>
                <option value="HGT-145">Endocrine Disorder (HGT-145)</option>
                <option value="HGT-146">Metabolic Disorder (HGT-146)</option>
                <option value="HGT-147">Neurological Disorder (HGT-147)</option>
                <option value="HGT-148">Pelvic Inflammatory Disease (HGT-148)</option>
                <option value="HGT-149">Renal Disease (HGT-149)</option>
                <option value="HGT-150">Visual Disorder (HGT-150)</option>
                <option value="HGT-151">Warfarin sensitivity (HGT-151)</option>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p id="icp" style="display:none;">
        <select id="panely" name="panely">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="HGC-152">Inherited Breast Cancer (HGC-152)</option>
                <option value="HGC-153">Comprehensive Inherited Cancer (HGC-153)</option>

        </select>
        </p>

        <p id="stp" style="display:none;">
        <select id="panelz" name="panelz">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="HGC-154">Somatic Cancer 15 genes Panel (HGC-154)</option>
                <option value="HGC-155">Somatic Cancer 26 genes Panel (HGC-155)</option>
                <option value="HGC-156">Somatic Cancer 170 genes Panel (HGC-156)</option>
        </select>
        </p>
    <br><br>
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">Reception date & time</h3>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="rectime" value="2017-09-18T12:00" required/>

    <select id="recby" name="recby" required>
                <option value="">-- Received by --</option>
                <option value="LA">LA</option>
                <option value="MA">MA</option>
                <option value="RZ">RZ</option>
                <option value="SP">SP</option>
                <option value="JA">JA</option>
        </select>

    <br><br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset  id="fieldset4">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Physician Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 4/5</h3>
    <input type="text" name="physician" placeholder="Physician Name" required />
    <input type="text" name="phyorganisation" placeholder="Organisation" required />
    <input type="text" name="phyphone" placeholder="Phone" required />
    <input type="text" name="phyfax" placeholder="Fax" required />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset  id="fieldset5">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Requester Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 5/5</h3>
    <input type="text" name="requester" placeholder="Requester Name" required />
    <input type="text" name="reqorganisation" placeholder="Organisation" required />
    <input type="text" name="reqphone" placeholder="Phone" required />
    <input type="text" name="reqfax" placeholder="Fax" required />
    <input type="email" name="reqemail" placeholder="Email" required />
    <input type="text" name="reqaddress" placeholder="Address" />
        <br><br>
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">Report must be released to </h3>
        <select id="sendto" name="sendto" required>
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="Physician">Physician</option>
                <option value="Requester">Requester</option>

        </select>
    <br><br>
    <h3 class="ft-subtitle" align="left">Via </h3>
        <select id="sendby" name="sendby" required>
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="HGC-154">Fax</option>
                <option value="HGC-154">E-mail</option>
                <option value="HGC-155">Direct collection</option>
                <option value="HGC-156">courier</option>
        </select>



    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" />
  </fieldset>

</form>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my .js

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return true;
})
```

here is my .css

```
    /*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/

    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/

}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#msform select {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;    
    background: #ffffff;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.top-title {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.info-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.ft-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
```

please can someone help me, I am not an expert in js code

I know that i need to add some function to control the validity of each field separately

Thank you

Comment: If you make some input errors let's say on the first step and click next, then go back with previous, do you see the errors ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you dont have to use $(document).ready.. on every function you use

you could have one $(document).ready

try after

$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

add this:

```
var inputs = current_fs.find(':input');
for(var i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++) {
         var element = inputs[i];
         // validate elements..
         // for example for required:
         if(element.hasAttribute('required')) {
             if($(element).val() == '') {
                 alert('a field is required');
                 // or do whatever you want with it..
             }
         }
     }
```

thank you :)

Comment: Thnak you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to call a validation function on clicking "next" before you go to the next step. I have provided a fiddle where you can see what i mean:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qq3oagk/)

**Updated Fiddle (validates radio buttons and selects too):**
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohngmksy/)

```
$(".next").click(function(){

    current_fs = $(this).parent();

    if( validateFieldset(current_fs.attr('id')) ) //function to validate this step
    {
     ....
    }

});
```

In this function you go through all required input fields and do your checks. In this simple case, i just checked if it has a value:

```
function validateFieldset(fieldset){
    valid = false;

$.each($('#'+fieldset+' input'),function(){ //go through all inputs

        //if an input field is required, but empty...add error class
    if($(this).prop('required') && $(this).val().length == 0){ 
    $(this).addClass("error");  
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass("error");  
  }

});

if($('.error').length == 0) //if no error class --> valid
{
    valid = true;
}

    return valid;

}
```

Finally you can add some css to highlight your error classes:

```
.error {
    border: solid 2px #FF0000 !important;  
}
```

Hope this is what your are looking for. :)

Comment: Thanks alot toffler!
But on google chrome the red warning don't work!! only on firefox 
i don't know way.

and the last form (n°5) don't use the same red warning but pop a text, can i keep the same Waring border red with the last form too ?

Comment: and this work only with the input, not with select or radio button 
but some of them need to be also validate .

thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: This is just a simply guidline of how you can validate each step.

Basically the whole wizard is one form, including all the former steps (fieldsets). Your last button is the submit-button, which submits the whole form (including the steps before this one). At this step all the required fields are automatically validated - that's why only this worked before. 

This is an updated fiddle, which validates radio buttons, selects and the last step in the same way too.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohngmksy/)

Comment: Thank alot dear toffler

Comment: hi dear 
I tire to learn to do it by my self hh but i guss i am not ready for that 
i want to add the validation for the textarea 
`
 //check if step has textarea
   $.each($('#'+fieldset+' textarea'),function(){ //go through all textarea

   //if an textarea field is required, but empty...add error class
     if($(this).prop('required') && $(this).val().length == 0){ 
       $(this).addClass("error");  
      }else{
       $(this).removeClass("error");  
      }
      }); `

but it is not working were is my mistake ?

Comment: You have to check if this page contains a textarea before validating, like i did with radiobuttons in the updated fiddle.
Adittionally you have to give the "required" property to your html textareas, like your input fields.

Then you should be fine with your code.